# How to know If I have Wifi driver installed

Tags: wireless, drivers

I am following [this guide](http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/07/learn-to-hack-wifi-password-with-ubuntu.html) to just test hacking Wifi, I have read in the manual of airmon-ng that entering the command airmon-ng will return interface status, under the chipset field it said "unknown". So I wanted to know if I have a Wifi driver installed or not, knowing that I have a perfectly fine Wifi connection.

Comment: If you have wifi connection, it's definitely installed. There can't be any question!

Answer (score 3):

You said you have a perfectly working Wifi connection, which means you have WiFi driver installed. Because, without a driver, you couldn't have a working connection.

As for the `airmon-ng` command, if the field under `Chipset` column is unknown, it means the program has no knowledge about the model/vendor of this chipset. It isn't an indicator of driver status. Driver name is under the column `Driver`. Here is the output I got running in my local PC

```
$  sudo airmon-ng
Interface       Chipset         Driver
wlp4s0          Intel 4965AGN   iwl4965 - [phy0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I have read the answer of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) and it appears that the driver is installed according to the table provided.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo airmon-ng
```

Running this may show what you want.

If you want all the drivers installed in your system then you must type in your terminal:

```
sudo lsmod
```